# How to match Window Title with double quotes in it without changing title match mode?

Tags: autohotkey

I have this window

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
ahk_class VirtualConsoleClass
```

I tried to find it with IfWinExist but would not succeed. I have tried

```
IfWinExist, ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\" ahk_class VirtualConsoleClass
IfWinExist, """C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\" ahk_class VirtualConsoleClass
```

Both are always false. What's the proper way of doing this. I'm reluctant to change title match mode...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Backtick `` ` `` to escape `"`

> IfWinExist, "`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\" ahk_class VirtualConsoleClass

Comment: Close. I had to remove the enclosing quotes to make it work. Like this: 
**IfWinExist, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\ ahk_class VirtualConsoleClass** Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: @zaphodtx I think I missed escaping the quote at the end. Can you check if ``"`"/dir/path`""`` works for you? If not, I'll update the answer to `"/dir/path as suggested.

Comment: Yes, that did work for me as well.  Sorry for the delayed response.